# Whitelabel error when i try make to make a get from database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to make a small rest-api in springboot but i always get this error[error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnzEz.png)
It is connected to a database but when I try to exceute a GET from Post I also have 404 error

This is my structure
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsz9F.png)

My pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>Clientix</groupId>
    <artifactId>Ruben_DeNicolas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Clientix</name>
    <description>TFG</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Repository

```
    package repositories;
    
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    
    import models.ClientesModel;
    
    @Repository
    public interface ClientesRepository extends CrudRepository<ClientesModel, Integer>{
    
    }
```

Service

```
    package services;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    import models.ClientesModel;
    import repositories.ClientesRepository;
    
    @Service
    public class ClientesService {
        @Autowired
        ClientesRepository clientesRepository;
    
        public ArrayList<ClientesModel>getClientes()
        {
            return(ArrayList<ClientesModel>)clientesRepository.findAll();
        }
        
        
        public ClientesModel insert(ClientesModel c)
        {
            
            return clientesRepository.save(c);
     
        }
    
    
        
    }
```

Model

```
    package models;
    
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "clientes")
    public class ClientesModel {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Integer idCliente;
        private String NombreCliente;
        private String CIFNIF;
        private String DireccionFacturacion;
    
        
    public ClientesModel(String NombreCliente) {
    
        this.NombreCliente = NombreCliente;
    
    }
    
    public ClientesModel(int idCliente, String NombreCliente, String CIFNIF, String DireccionFacturacion) {
        this.idCliente = idCliente;
        this.NombreCliente = NombreCliente;
        this.CIFNIF = CIFNIF;
        this.DireccionFacturacion = DireccionFacturacion;
    }
    
    public Integer getIdCliente() {
        return idCliente;
    }
    
    public void setIdCliente(Integer idCliente) {
        this.idCliente = idCliente;
    }
    
    public String getNombreCliente() {
        return NombreCliente;
    }
    
    public void setNombreCliente(String nombreCliente) {
        NombreCliente = nombreCliente;
    }
    
    public String getCIFNIF() {
        return CIFNIF;
    }
    
    public void setCIFNIF(String cIFNIF) {
        CIFNIF = cIFNIF;
    }
    
    public String getDireccionFacturacion() {
        return DireccionFacturacion;
    }
    
    public void setDireccionFacturacion(String direccionFacturacion) {
        DireccionFacturacion = direccionFacturacion;
    }

}
```

Controller

````
package controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import models.ClientesModel;
import services.ClientesService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/clientes",produces="application/json")
public class ClientesController {
    @Autowired
    ClientesService clientesService; 
    
    
    
    //OBTENER TODOS LOS CLIENTES
    //@RequestMapping(value = "/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @GetMapping()
    public ArrayList<ClientesModel> getClientes()
    {
    return clientesService.getClientes();
    
    }
    
    //INSTERTAR CLIENTE
    @PostMapping
    public ClientesModel insert(@RequestBody ClientesModel c)
    {
        return this.clientesService.insert(c);
    }
    
    
}
```
````

Clientix application

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;



@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan()
public class ClientixApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientixApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is the SpringBoot log

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.6)

2022-04-06 16:05:32.098  INFO 15728 --- [           main] C.Ruben_DeNicolas.ClientixApplication    : Starting ClientixApplication using Java 17.0.2 on DESKTOP-0EJNGE1 with PID 15728 (C:\Users\Rubén\Desktop\TestSpringBoot\Ruben_DeNicolas (1)\Ruben_DeNicolas\target\classes started by Rubén in C:\Users\Rubén\Desktop\TestSpringBoot\Ruben_DeNicolas (1)\Ruben_DeNicolas)
2022-04-06 16:05:32.101  INFO 15728 --- [           main] C.Ruben_DeNicolas.ClientixApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-04-06 16:05:32.373  INFO 15728 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-04-06 16:05:32.381  INFO 15728 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 2 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-04-06 16:05:32.627  INFO 15728 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-04-06 16:05:32.632  INFO 15728 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-04-06 16:05:32.632  INFO 15728 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.60]
2022-04-06 16:05:32.692  INFO 15728 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-04-06 16:05:32.692  INFO 15728 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 569 ms
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2022-04-06 16:05:32.784  INFO 15728 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-04-06 16:05:32.810  INFO 15728 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.7.Final
2022-04-06 16:05:32.893  INFO 15728 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-04-06 16:05:32.945  INFO 15728 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-04-06 16:05:32.948  WARN 15728 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2022-04-06 16:05:33.018  INFO 15728 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-04-06 16:05:33.034  INFO 15728 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
2022-04-06 16:05:33.132  INFO 15728 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-04-06 16:05:33.138  INFO 15728 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-04-06 16:05:33.156  WARN 15728 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-04-06 16:05:33.313  INFO 15728 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-04-06 16:05:33.319  INFO 15728 --- [           main] C.Ruben_DeNicolas.ClientixApplication    : Started ClientixApplication in 1.398 seconds (JVM running for 1.705)
2022-04-06 16:05:36.286  INFO 15728 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-04-06 16:05:36.287  INFO 15728 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-04-06 16:05:36.287  INFO 15728 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

what is the url your hitting on your browser, make sure not hitting with https...
Code looks okay, try hitting

```
http://localhost:8080/clientes
```

Comment: Hi Navneet, it did not work but thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).